# Cleaning up `case class` with `Option` FIelds

Tags: scala, shapeless

Given:

```
case class Foo(a: Option[Int], b: Option[Int], c: Option[Int], d: Option[Int])
```

I'd like to only allow constructing a `Foo` **only** if at least one of its arguments is `Some`, i.e. not all fields are `None`.

It would be quite a bit of code to write an Algebraic Data Type, and then make sub-classes for each variant:

```
sealed trait Foo
case class HasAOnly(a: Int)      extends Foo
case class HasAB(a: Int, b: Int) extends Foo
// etc...
```

Is there a cleaner, i.e. less code, way to address my problem using `shapeless`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to the `sealed abstract case class` trick which Rob Norris recently [publicised](https://gist.github.com/tpolecat/a5cb0dc9adeacc93f846835ed21c92d2), you can keep the characteristics of your `Foo` case class but also provide your own smart constructor which returns an `Option[Foo]` depending on whether the given arguments pass all your criteria or not:

```
sealed abstract case class Foo(
  a: Option[Int], b: Option[Int], c: Option[Int], d: Option[Int])

object Foo {
  private class Impl(
    a: Option[Int], b: Option[Int], c: Option[Int], d: Option[Int])
    extends Foo(a, b, c, d)

  def apply(
    a: Option[Int],
    b: Option[Int],
    c: Option[Int],
    d: Option[Int]): Option[Foo] =
    (a, b, c, d) match {
      case (None, None, None, None) => None
      case _ => Some(new Impl(a, b, c, d))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do something like this with nested `Ior`s:

```
import cats.data.Ior

case class Foo(iors: Ior[Ior[Int, Int], Ior[Int, Int]]) {
  def a: Option[Int] = iors.left.flatMap(_.left)
  def b: Option[Int] = iors.left.flatMap(_.right)
  def c: Option[Int] = iors.right.flatMap(_.left)
  def d: Option[Int] = iors.right.flatMap(_.right)
}
```

Now it's impossible to construct a `Foo` with all `None`s. You could also make the case class constructor private and have the `Ior` logic happen in an alternative constructor on the companion object, which would make pattern matching a little nicer, but it would also make the example a little longer.

Unfortunately this is kind of clunky to use. What you really want is a generalization of `Ior` in the same way that `shapeless.Coproduct` is a generalization of `Either`. I'm not personally aware of a ready-made version of anything like that, though.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend providing a builder pattern for your class. This is especially useful if the users of your library typically only specify some of the many optional parameters. And as a bonus with the separate methods per parameter they won't have to wrap everything in `Some`

You can use a single type parameter on the class to mark if it's complete (i.e. has at least one `Some` parameter) and you can enforce this on the build method with an implicit parameter.

```
sealed trait Marker
trait Ok extends Marker
trait Nope extends Markee

case class Foo private(a: Option[Int], b: Option[Int], c: Option[Int], d: Option[Int])

object Foo{
  case class Builder[T <: Marker](foo: Foo){
    def a(x:Int) = Builder[Ok](foo = foo.copy(a=Some(x)))
    def b(x:Int) = Builder[Ok](foo = foo.copy(b=Some(x)))
    // ...

    def build(implicit ev: T <:< Ok) = foo
  }

  def create = Builder[Nope](Foo(None, None, None, None))
}
```

I have experimented with a type-safe builder before. This gist has a more complex example, although that also keeps track which field has been set, so that it can be extracted later without an unsafe call to `Option.get`.
https://gist.github.com/gjuhasz86/70cb1ca2cc057dac5ba7